# Vulkan ignoring GLSL image format qualifier

Tags: vulkan

I have a compute shader that reads a signed normalized integer image using `imageLoad`.

The image itself (which contains both positive and negative values) is created as a `R16G16_SNORM` and is written by a fragment shader in a previous gpass.
The imageview bound to the descriptorsetlayout binding in the compute shader is also created with the same `R16G16_SNORM` format.

Everything works as expected.

Yesterday I realized that in the compute shader I used the wrong image format qualifier `rg16`.
A bit puzzled (I could not understand how it could work properly reading an unsigned normalized value) I corrected to `rg16_snorm`, and.. nothing changed.

I performed several tests (I even specified a `rg16f`) and always had the same (correct, [-1,1] signed) result.

It seems like Vulkan (at least my implementation) silently ignores any image format qualifier, and falls back (I guess) to the imageview format bound to the descriptorset.

This seems to be in line with the spec regarding format in imageview creation

> format is a VkFormat describing the format and type used to interpret texel blocks in the image

but then in Appendix A (Vulkan Environment for SPIR-V - "Compatibility Between SPIR-V Image Formats And Vulkan Formats") there is a clear distinction between Rg16 and Rg16Snorm.. so:

is it a bug or a feature?

I am working with an Nvidia 2070 Super under ubuntu 20.04

**UPDATE**

The initial image writing operation happens as the result of a fragment shader color attachment output, and as such, there is no descriptorsetlayout binding declaration. The fragment shader outputs a `vec2` to the `R16G16_SNORM` color attachment as specified by the active framebuffer and renderpass.

The resulting image (after the relevant barriers) is *then* read (correctly, despite the wrong layout qualifier) by a compute shader as an image/imageLoad operation.

Note that validation layers are enabled and silent.

Note also that the resulting values are far from random, and exactly match the expected values (both positive and negative), using either `rg16`, `rg16f` or `rg16_snorm`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is undefined behavior.

There is a validation check on Image Write Operations that prevents the `OpTypeImage`'s format (equivalent to the `layout` format specifier in GLSL) from being incompatible with the backing `VkImageView`'s format:

> If the image format of the `OpTypeImage` is not compatible with the `VkImageView`’s format, the write causes the contents of the image’s memory to become undefined.

Note that when it says "compatible", it doesn't mean image view compatibility; it means ["exactly match"](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/chap44.html#spirvenv-image-formats). Your `OpTypeImage` format did not exactly match that of the shader, so your writes were undefined. And "undefined" can mean "works as if you had specified the correct format".

Comment: Thanks Nicol Bolas, I am afraid I missed some useful information, so I added an update in the question that should affect your answer, sorry about that. Please have a look at the update part. Thanks

Comment: I have found in section 15.3.1.: "There are a number of cases where a SPIR-V instruction can mismatch with the sampler, the imageview, or both. [...] In such cases the value of the texel returned is undefined." One of the possible cause is: "The SPIR-V Image Format is not compatible with the image view’s format". Could it be that the layout declaration is not compatible (ie exactly equal) to the actual image format, and the resulting read, at least in this implementation, uses the imageview format?

Comment: But can a imageLoad with a wrong layout qualifier count as a SPIR-V instruction mismatch?